# able to load external image onto bitmap for drawingboard

Tags: flash

Here is my new code but it does not render external image, please help.

```
//load libs
import flash.net.*;
import flash.geom.Matrix;
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import com.adobe.images.JPGEncoder;

function myLoader() {
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, sketch);

    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.sergiorodriguez.org/images/2008_5_FXD_VividBlack.jpg");
    loader.load(request);
    //addChild(loader);

}

//action for mouse 
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, moveCursor);
Mouse.hide();

function moveCursor(event:MouseEvent):void{
    pencil.x = event.stageX;
    pencil.y = event.stageY;
}


var canvas_mc;
    canvas_mc = new MovieClip()

addChildAt(canvas_mc,0);
canvas_mc.swapDepths

//draw area to sketch
function sketch(e:Event):void{
    //load bitmap and draw it to memory
    var myBitmapData;
        myBitmapData = new BitmapData(500, 500);
        myBitmapData.draw(e);

    //define matrix
    var matrix;
        matrix = new flash.geom.Matrix();

    //start canvas
    canvas_mc.graphics.beginBitmapFill(myBitmapData,matrix, true, true);
    canvas_mc.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    canvas_mc.graphics.endFill();

    //listening  events
    canvas_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDrawing);
    canvas_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDrawing);
    canvas_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, makeLine);    
}       

//mouse draws on press
function startDrawing(event:MouseEvent):void{   
    canvas_mc.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0, 1);
    canvas_mc.graphics.moveTo(mouseX, mouseY);
    canvas_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, makeLine);
}

//mouse stops drawing on realese
function stopDrawing(event:MouseEvent):void{
    canvas_mc.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, makeLine);
}

//creates lines
function makeLine(event:MouseEvent):void{
    canvas_mc.graphics.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);  
}

//call function
myLoader()

//start to save onto server
var serverPath:String = "";
function createJPG(m:MovieClip, q:Number, fileName:String){
    var jpgSource:BitmapData = new BitmapData (m.width, m.height);
    jpgSource.draw(m);
    var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(q);
    var jpgStream:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(jpgSource);
    var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader ("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");
    var jpgURLRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest ( serverPath+"jpg_encoder_download.php?name=" + fileName + ".jpg");       
    jpgURLRequest.requestHeaders.push(header);              
    jpgURLRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;               
    jpgURLRequest.data = jpgStream;

    var jpgURLLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();   
    //jpgURLLoader.load(jpgURLRequest);     
    navigateToURL(jpgURLRequest, "_blank");
}

save_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, saveBtnPress);
save_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, saveBtnOver);
save_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, saveBtnOut);

function saveBtnPress(e:Event):void{    
createJPG(canvas_mc, 90, "sketch");
}

function saveBtnOver(e:Event):void{ 
    Mouse.show();
    pencil.visible = false;
}

function saveBtnOut(e:Event):void{  
    Mouse.hide();
    pencil.visible = true;
}
```

Comment: You *really* should make sure to type your variables, that will save you alot of hassle down the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for the image to load before you can draw it:

```
public function LoaderExample() {
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleComplete);

    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("www.foo.com/image.jpg");
    loader.load(request);
}

public function handleComplete(e:Event):void {
    //do stuff with the image here
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I loaded the image but still does not show.

Comment: Thanks for you help it worked :). I needed to call the function sketch() on a completed event then draw the image.